# How can I rotate Cubemap?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, shader, shaderlab

I am currently working on some reflection shaders in Unity. And I am totally newbie about shaders.
I found an article about cubemap rotation. I' ve done some implementation but it seems doesn't work properly. I rotated cubemap in vertex shader with only rotate normal.
How can I achive [this](http://24bitgames.com/2014/11/10/fun-with-cubemaps/) effect?

```
 float3 RotateAroundYInDegrees (float3 vertex, float degrees)
      {
         float alpha = degrees * UNITY_PI / 180.0;
         float sina, cosa;
         sincos(alpha / 2, sina, cosa);
         float3x3 m = float3x3(cosa, 0, sina, 0, 1, 0, -sina, 0, cosa);
        float3 r = float3(mul(m, vertex.xyz) ).rgb;
        return r;
    }
    void vert (inout appdata_full v, out Input o) {
        UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input,o);
        v.normal = RotateAroundYInDegrees(v.normal, _Rotate);
      }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to get into shader coding ? If not, there is the Shader Graph (in unity packages) that is much (much) simpler to use and can achieve almost everything (as it now support custom nodes)

Comment: Yes I really want to get into shader coding. And you are right about shader graph. But I'd like to coding for now.

Comment: Your code does what you expect from the method name : the normal is rotated around the vertical axis. The question is : what do you want to do? You haven't implemented any of the specific details of the article you link, which itself has a pretty convoluted way of achieving its effect. They use a reflection vector, multiple samples of the cubemap and blending between them based on normal.